# Space and time complexity of recursive implementation of summation function

Tags: python, performance, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

Can anyone advise the space and time complexity of the below code?
I know that the time complexity should be O(n) because the function is called n times, and the space complexity is at least O(n) (because of stack space), but does passing a[1:] to function result in an increase in the space complexity? I think a[1:] will create a new copy of *a* while omitting the first element, is that right?

```
def sum(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    return a[0] + sum(a[1:])
```

Comment: " I know that the time complexity should be O(n) because the function is called n times," It isn't. Definitely, the function is called N times, so it is *at least* O(N)... but you are doing something in the function, no? It it isn't constant time. So it isn't going to be O(N)... So yea, you're right about `a[1:]`. And the result is that your time complexity is O(N**2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a recursive function, if no [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations are applied, it will certainly have a space complexity of at least `O(n)` in this case, considering its execution on the memory stack. But let us analyze it further:

**Time complexity**

We know that sum is recursive and its stop criteria is when the input array is single length. So we know that `Sum` will be called at least `O(n)` times in the worst-case scenario, considering an input array of size `n`. Consider the recursion for what it is, i. e., a **loop**.

Inside the function, however, we have a slice operation. The slice operation `l[a:b]` is `O(b-a)`, so this operation will have a complexity of `O(n-1)` in the first run, `O(n-2)` in the second run, and so on. We consider that primitively, it will perform a copy of the whole array. The overall time complexity for this function should be `O(n^2)` because it creates a slice per item in an array of size `n`.

**Space complexity**

Now talking about space in memory.

```py
len(a) == 1
```

Here we have one copy from the return value of len(a).

```py
return a[0]
```

&

```py
    return a[0] + sum(a[1:])
```

In the both lines above we'll have another copy of a value that will be stored into the return address of the function. The slice also has a `O(n)` space complexity.

Seeing this, and considering no major-breaking optimizations are being applied by the compiler, such as a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), we say that the space complexity of this function is `O(n)` because it will make a **constant** number of copies for each input AND will perform a slice operation in a array of size `n`.

Since we said in the beginning that recursion is like a loop, considering no tail-call optimizations, this whole function will be performed `n` times in the worst-case scenario. The program will increase the function's memory stack until it reaches the stop criteria, until it can finally 'pop' return values from the stack of calls. The total space complexity is thus `O(n*log n)` as well (because every execution the input array is smaller).

**Ps:**

I also considered `len(a)` to have an `O(1)` time complexity, according to [this](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt).

Comment: " complexity of O(n-1) in the first run, O(n-2) in the second run, and so on. We consider that primitively, it will perform a copy of the whole array. The time complexity for this function should be O(n*log n) because of the amortizing factor." I don't follow. The way I see it, for a given sequence of size `N`, you create slices of sizes `N-1, N-2, ..., 3, 2, 1` you have `n*(n-1)/2` so `O(N^2)` Saying it has a complexity of O(N-1) on the first call, O(N-2) on the second isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is something like theta(n^2) because each time you do a[i:] you basically copy the list from i to the end, so you have to iterate through it. As for space complexity, the app stack will have all of your lists that you will call, first a list with n elements, then n-1 and so on until 1, where you will start emptying the stack. So you will end up with a theta(n^2) complexity for that too.